# Failed to find '?attr/colorPrimaryDark' in current theme. Android 3.0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gradle-plugin

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/action_bar_color"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbars="none"
tools:context="com.ndm.ndmsalessoft.MainActivity">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/data"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="40dp">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="91dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cerrebro_icon_login" />


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dada"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center|bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/cust_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/text_Input_Layout_top_margin"
                android:textColorHint="@color/white"

                >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/user_editText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/loginId"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/edit_text_size"
                    android:theme="@style/MyEditTextTheme"

                    />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/cust_catag"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/text_Input_Layout_top_margin"
                android:textColorHint="@color/white">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/pass_editText2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableBottom="@color/grey"
                    android:hint="@string/Password"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/edit_text_size"
                    android:theme="@style/MyEditTextTheme"

                    />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


            <com.ndm.font.CustomFontButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:text="Forgot Password?"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@color/edit_text_color"
                android:textStyle="italic" />


            <com.ndm.font.CustomFontButton
                android:id="@+id/procced"
                android:layout_width="170dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/button_style"
                android:onClick="onLogin"
                android:text="@string/LoginButton"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Theme NotitleBar is selected because when app theme was there that shows
The following classes could not be instantiated: - android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache) - android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

[image]

Comment: in android studio 2.3 that was working properly After Android 3.0 That shows the error like those

Comment: have you tried to refresh the gradle in the gradle properties

Comment: Yes I refresh the gradle, clean, rebuild project and also invalidate caches/restart .